# Moving focus out of TextBox

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, powerpoint, activex

An ActiveX TextBox provides `Edit` command in the right-click menu that you can choose to go to Edit mode type directly in the TextBox. You can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> at any time to go back to Normal mode. VBA equivalent of the first action (go to Edit mode) is:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox21").OLEFormat.DoVerb
```

But I haven't been able to find the equivalent of the second action, i.e. moving back to Normal mode. Does anyone know?

*N.B. Problem is not specific to PowerPoint, so I've added excel tag to attract more experts.*

Comment: Give something else the focus. "Something" always has focus.

Comment: Yeah. I thought of moving focus to the parent Slide, but there doesn't seem to be any method of doing that. `Slide.Select()` didn't do the trick.

Comment: Perhaps something lke `Selection.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary` ? ...Check out [DoVerb Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/oleformat-doverb-method-powerpoint) vs. [Verb Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/oleobject-verb-method-excel), also [AutoActivate Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245027(v=vs.60).aspx) and [Verb VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445764(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any built-in method for moving back to Normal mode. What I did at the end was to use `SendKeys.Send("{Esc}")`. This successfully brings the TextBox back to normal mode. However, this approach does have some caveats. Firstly if current focus is not in the slide (e.g. you're using the Ribbon, or have a dialog open), <kbd>Esc</kbd> can have unwanted effects (such as cancelling the dialog) and would not bring the TextBox to Normal state. Secondly if you have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys down, sending in <kbd>Esc</kbd> will open Windows Start menu.

Barring these nuisances, the method itself works fine in my situation. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding your situation entirely, but the following works for me. The `Select` method will select any Shape on the Slide, even if the focus is in the ActiveX control. And then, if you really want the ActiveX control to be selected (but not in editing mode), select it again.

```
Dim p as Presentation
Dim s as Slide
Dim shp as Shape

Set p = ActivePresentation
Set s = p.Slides(1)
Set shp1 = s.Shapes(1)
Set shp2 = s.Shapes("TextBox3")
shp2.OLEFormat.DoVerb
shp2.OLEFormat.Object.Text = "test"
shp1.Select 'transitory
shp2.Select
```

Comment: Thanks Cindy, but I do not have any other thing on my slide.

Comment: @dotNet Put a small Shape on it, no outline, no background, etc?

Comment: For a second this looked like a solution But alas, selecting another object doesn't bring TextBox out of Edit mode.